# Expo : Invalid sdkVersion "32.0.0"

Tags: react-native, expo

while trying to running react-native app according to installation guide using expo configuration i caught this error ?

> Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0,
>   13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0

this is my expo config in app.json :

> "expo": {
>       "name": "expo_demoproject2",
>       "slug": "expo_demoproject2",
>       "privacy": "public",
>       "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
>       "platforms": [
>         "ios",
>         "android"
>       ]

My development environment :

> node -v : 10.15.3 ||  npm -v : 6.4.1 || npm ls expo : expo@32.0.6 || yarn
>   list react-native :V0.57.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the relevant part of your stack trace is the following:

> Error: Invalid sdkVersion

Then it tells you `Expo` *supports `SdkVersion`: 10 through 31 inclusive*, but within your `app.json` file **you're trying to use version 32**.

```
"sdkVersion": "32.0.0", "platforms": [ "ios", "android" ]
```

Maybe you could try bumping that version down to 31 and seeing if that resolves your issue:

```
"sdkVersion": "31.0.0", "platforms": [ "ios", "android" ]
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: by default when you create react-native app using expo , it use latest sdkVersion that is currently 32.0.0 and it's incompatible!. anyway i used your recommendation and my problem was solved

Comment: See [Expo instructions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/) to upgrade in case of any other version number