# Expo ERROR 11:50 Error: Invalid sdkVersion

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using Expo to create a react-native application,
when I run `npm start` it runs only on the web, but the android run gives me the following error

> ERROR 11:50 Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0.0,
> 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 37.0.0, 38.0.0

I am working with :

**Expo 3.27.14**

**npm  6.14.5**

**node v12.18.3**

**create-react-native 3.5.0**

I saw this solution [Expo : Invalid sdkVersion "32.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538925/expo-invalid-sdkversion-32-0-0)
but I don't even have the `app.json` file contains `sdkVersion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `package.json` you have `dependencies` which should contain `expo`.
This is your expo sdk version.

In order to have the up to date sdk version (currently 39) you should run

> expo update

in your console.